# How do I automatically serve CSS stylesheets and JS scripts using ktor?

Tags: kotlin, ktor

I am trying to setup a local server for API-callback using ktor under `localhost:8080`. The purpose of this server is to:

1. Get the API response code from the URL parameters
2. Serve a webpage under the same URL that shows the user the state of the callback

Currently i have this code:

```kotlin
  fun Application.configureRouting() {
    staticResources(remotePath = "/callback", basePackage = "static") {
      enableAutoHeadResponse()

      get {
        val params: Parameters = call.parameters
        val requestState = AuthState(params["state"]!!)

        if (!AuthState.currentlyUsedStates.contains(requestState))
          throw Exception("Request Cancelled, State forgery was detected.")

          val response = AuthorizationResponse
          val responseData = response.data

          responseData.state = params["state"]!!

          if (params.contains("code"))
            responseData.code = params["code"]

          if (params.contains("error"))
            responseData.error = params["error"]

          response.save()
          requestState.remove()
      }
    }
  }
```

File structure:

```
projectRoot
  └── src/
    └── main/
      └── resources/
        └── static/
          ├── css/
          │   ├── style.css
          │   ├── light.css
          │   └── dark.css
          ├── js/
          │   ├── theme.js
          │   └── main.js
          └── index.html
```

index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dark.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/light.css">
    <title>Callback</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Website layout and stuff -->
</body>

<script src="js/theme.js"></script>
<script src="js/callback.js"></script>
</html>
```

---

Now my problem is that neither the stylesheets linked in the `<head>` nor the scripts referenced by the `src` attribute are actually served to the user when requesting the page, resulting in the bare-bones unstyled HTML look. **So how do I automatically send them along the index.html?**

I have read through old stackoverflow questions and articles but all of them seem to be very outdated and using deprecated methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sooo, appearently the fix was really simple. I just had to change the link to the files from a relative link to a static link.

Like this:
`before.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dark.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/light.css">
    <title>Callback</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Website layout and stuff -->
</body>

<script src="js/theme.js"></script>
<script src="js/callback.js"></script>
</html>
```

`after.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8080/callback/css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8080/callback/css/dark.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost:8080/callback/css/light.css">
    <title>Callback</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Website layout and stuff -->
</body>

<script src="http://localhost:8080/callback/js/theme.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8080/callback/js/callback.js"></script>
</html>
```

Or in more general:
`./subfolder/file.ext`
had to turn into
`http://localhost:8080/callback/subfolder/file.ext`

Answer (score -1):

Try to define a separate `static` route with `remotePath` set to `/callback` that'll serves the static resources also `basePackage` is not needed for serving resources from a folder so you can remove it:

```
fun Application.configureRouting() {
    static("/callback") {
        resources("static")
    }

    get("/callback") {
        // your existing code
    }
}
```

Hope this'll work for you I can't test it right now

Comment: Hey, thanks for the quick answer, however this not what I am looking for. `static() { ... }` got deprecated an replaced. Also, I have tried to set up the `get` and the `staticResources` in parallel like that and got an error.

Comment: can you explain what error you facing?

Comment: I don't exactly get an error that prevents the website from being served, however the stylesheets and scripts are not. The served page and the console + sources can be found here: https://imgur.com/a/9EP1mAb